# Doctrine : Does the placement of a property in a doctrine entity affect merge/persist?

Tags: php, entity-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity

I am using Doctrine 2.5.0 and I am fairly new to it.

**I would like to know why the position of the properties and associations affects the saving of the entity.**

I have an entity with some properties and some associations. I recently noticed this on at least 3 different entities that if a property is placed after an association, it would not be updated in the database (using merge and flush).

So, in the below entity, the name and other properties do not get updated.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 */

class Product
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=8)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Shop")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shopId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $shop;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $name;

/*Some other properties*/

/*Getters and Setters*/     
}
```

But this gets updated. Notice the position of the $name (and all the other properties) and $shop.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="products"
 * )
 */
class Product
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=8)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $name;

/*ALL other properties*/

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Shop")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shopId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $shop;

/*Getters and Setters*/     
}
```

I thought of changing the positions because in one of my entities I noticed that only the properties placed after the associations were not getting updated in the database.